# Codeigniter form not submitting

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, validation

I have using codeigniter form validation library to validate a form, below is the logic in my controller,

```
public function addJob()
{
    $this->load->model('jobwall');
    if($query = $this->jobwall->getjobTitles())
    {
        $data['select_options'] = $query;
    }
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('job_title', 'Job title', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('job_location', 'Job location', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('job_postcode', 'Job postcode', 'required|trim|min_length[5]|max_length[8]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('basic_salary', 'Basic Salary', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bonuses_available', 'bonuses_available', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('benefits', 'Benefits', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('key_skills', 'Key skills', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('retrain_position', 'Retrain position', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('job_summary', 'Job summary', 'required|trim|max_length[320]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('job_desc', 'Job description', 'required|trim');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //die(var_dump($_POST));
        $this->template->build('admin/jobwall/addjob', $data);
    } else {
        $this->load->model('jobwall');
        if($query = $this->jobwall->saveJobToWall()){
            $this->jobwall->makeRelationship();
            redirect('dashboard/jobwall');
        }
    }
    $this->template->build('admin/jobwall/addjob', $data);
}
```

What ever I try the form returns false the page just reloads the form (as specified in the false condition), however it should be returning false for validation. Can anybody see anything wrong in my post data?

```
 array(11) {
  ["job_title"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["job_location"]=>
  string(12) "Huddersfield"
  ["job_postcode"]=>
  string(7) "HD3 4AG"
  ["basic_salary"]=>
  string(19) "£15,000 - £20,000"
  ["bonus_available"]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  ["benefits"]=>
  string(33) "Great job, working on great sites"
  ["key_skills"]=>
  string(14) "PHP, CSS, HTML"
  ["retrain_position"]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  ["job_summary"]=>
  string(228) "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.o the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
  ["job_desc"]=>
  string(743) "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
  ["submit_job"]=>
  string(10) "Submit job"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you getting any error messages? and why are you using `$this->template->build('admin/jobwall/addjob', $data);` twice?

I would try to add a `return;` after the the redirect function, or delete the last line.

lets take a look:

```
// Step 1: check if everything is valid
// If not, it will build your template
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->template->build('admin/jobwall/addjob', $data);
}
// If yes...
else {
    $this->load->model('jobwall');
    if($query = $this->jobwall->saveJobToWall()){ // How do you handle your post here? Is it inside the model?
        $this->jobwall->makeRelationship();
        redirect('dashboard/jobwall');
        return; // to make sure that your code isn't running until the end of the fn
    }
}
// Step 2: You build the template for a 2nd time (if the validation did not pass), that could be a reason why your redirect isn't working, but i'm not sure
$this->template->build('admin/jobwall/addjob', $data)
```